# UI stucks in UWP App

Tags: c#, web-services, mvvm, uwp

I'm currently working on UWP apps, In that I'm using MVVM pattern. And also used the webservices to get the data. When I'm trying to navigate to one page to another page or clicking any control the app got struck, i don't know the exact reason.

For example, in my app i have Userprofile Page, in that I'm binding the data to show the user details for that I'm calling the webservice to get the data, I have webservice method in service class and service calling method in viewmodel and i'm calling the viewmodel method in my .cs file. In this scenario also my app got strucked,

My code:

```
  public async Task<ObservableCollection<CoverageModel>> GetCoverageDetailsForUserAsync()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var CoverageDetailsList = new ObservableCollection<CoverageModel>();

        try
        {
            HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, App.Base_Url + "api/User/GetCoverageDetailsOfUser");
            requestMessage.Headers.Add("authorization", App.TokenType + " " + App.AccessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response1 = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            var responsedata = await response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JObject data = JObject.Parse(responsedata);
            var page = data.SelectToken("<Result>k__BackingField");
            var result = page.ToObject<CoverageModel>();
            App.CoverageId = result.CoverageID;
            CoverageDetailsList.Add(result);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        return CoverageDetailsList;
    }
```

and my viewmodel code:

```
 public async void GetCoverageDetailsList()
    {
        IsProcessing = true;
        var userdetails = await UserManagementService.GetCoverageDetailsForUserAsync();
    var   collection = new ObservableCollection<AFUI>();
        if (userdetails[0].AF!= null)
        {
            foreach (var item in userdetails[0].AF)
            {

                AFUI Af = new AFUI ();
                Af.Number = userdetails[0].AF.IndexOf(item) + 1;
                //Af = item.AF[0];
                Af.Fee = item.Fee;
                //"$" + "" +
                Af.JobTitle = item.JobTitle;
                Af.JobType = item.JobType;
                Af.AFID= item.AFID;
                Af.EditImage = "\xE28F";
                collection.Add(Af);

            }
            CoverageCollection = collection;
        }

        IsProcessing = false;
    }

private RelayCommand _getCoverageListCommand;
    public RelayCommand GetCoverageListCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _getCoverageListCommand
                ?? (_getCoverageListCommand = new RelayCommand(GetCoverageDetailsList));
        }
    }
```

I'm calling that command in .cs file OnNavigatedTo Method

```
       protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            if (VM.GetCoverageListCommand.CanExecute(null))
                VM.GetCoverageListCommand.Execute(null);


        }
```

And in my xaml, I'm using Sync fusion control SFDataGrid. Simply I'm  binding the ItemSource = CoverageCollection; to that datagrid control to display the list of coverages

This is what I'm using to calling the webservice and binding.

Comment: Can you provide relevant code?

Comment: Please add some relevant code :)

Comment: Code would be of help, but it sounds like a threading issue, are you using async/await correctly when requesting the data from the web service?

Comment: Hi Clint, Thanks for your reply i'm using async and await methods when requesting the data from the web service.